# Move email using MailKit Pop3

Tags: c#, pop3, mailkit

I'm using **MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client** to access the email account, so far every thing is OK.

Now I'm trying to move an email message to another folder and can't find a way to do it. Anyone know how?

```cs
using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("server", 995, true);
    client.Authenticate("username", "password");

    int count = client.GetMessageCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var message = client.GetMessage(i);
        if (message.Subject.Contains("Test"))
        {
            //Move email here
            //Ex: MoveTo INBOX\Test
        }
    }

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

PS: What I want is not `client.DeleteMessage(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. POP3 has no concept of server-side folders. There is only the one (inbox). Maybe the server also offers IMAP?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It has IMAP I'll switch to it.